# How to update or get branches with Git-Plus

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I just start using GitHub for a project. I managed to set up GitHub, Atom, and Git-Plus package, so everything works fine. The problem is that I don't know how to update or get branches from GitHub repository.

For example, I created a new branch test-br, in the project it show me only master

```
$ git branch
* master
```

Comment: Did you create this branch locally on your computer, or on github?

Comment: I created it on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a remote branch. In order to see it you much first fetch it, e.g.:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

And then list the local copies of the remote branches:

```
$ git branch -r
```

You should see something like `origin/test-br` there.

Comment: I still not shown in Atom [Image](https://pp.userapi.com/c836532/v836532059/4d774/FLpagh9_gUc.jpg)

Comment: @Timur, why do you have `origin/test-br2` and `origin/test-br3`? @mureinik's approach should work.

Comment: test-br2 and br3 i created both on GitHub just for testing, the problem is that they are still not  being shown in **[Atom](https://pp.userapi.com/c836532/v836532059/4d783/hiwUS3dp7o0.jpg)**

Comment: OK, his solution is more on git side. I need to check how Atom works.